# ¿Cómo mantener el usuario guardado en el <form> aún escribiendo mal la contraseña?

Tags: php, formularios, login

Supongamos que tenemos un formulario, y sus validaciones escritas con PHP. Las variables se recogen con POST, hay dos campos (usuario y contraseña), y un botón de enviar.

Pues bien, el usuario introduce sus credenciales y por algún casual escribe mal la contraseña. Me gustaría que el nombre del usuario, por lo menos, quedara grabado en el `<input>` para que no tuviera que volver a escribirlo otra vez.

Comment: Has probado algo como `localStorage`?

Comment: No tenía conocimiento de localStorage... Gracias, le echaré un vistazo @lois6b

Comment: Una vez lo investigues e intentes, si tienes problemas concretos o errores, edita la pregunta para explicarlo siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Si publicas el código HTML del formulario podría agregarte el código PHP necesario para mantener el mismo usuario que se envió en el formulario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Si quieres que el formulario muestre el mismo usuario cuando la comprobación de usuario/contraseña es incorrecta puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['usuario']) === false) {
  /* Hacer comprobaciones de entrada */
}
/* Si la entrada fue infructuosa muestras el formulario como de costumbre */
?><form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <input
    type="text" name="usuario"
    value="<?= isset($_POST['usuario'])?htmlspecialchars($_POST['usuario']):'' ?>"
  />
</form>
```

Como puedes ver, en caso de que se hubiera enviado previamente el formulario, el campo `value` será rellenado con el valor de éste haciendo uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para convertir caracteres especiales en entidades HTML (como las comillas `"` que cerrarían el campo `value` prematuramente).

Comment: Siendo Php, y yo un desconocedor de éste,  no se me ocurrió enviarse el usuario a si mismo en caso de fallo de autenticación.

Comment: Por norma general es una costumbre en casi todos los tutoriales enviarse el formulario a sí mismo y en caso de ser correcta la autenticación se usa una cabecera HTTP `Location` para enviar el usuario a la zona privada y en caso contrario se vuelve a mostrar el mismo HTML (por haberse accedido la misma página). Imaginé que lo hacía así por "desaparecer" el usuario en la nueva carga del formulario, efecto muy común en este tipo de situaciones. Si no es así espero que dé más detalles del proceso de autenticación que usa.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias, siento no haber aportado código para hacer la solución más precisa, era una duda personal, para aplicar en futuros proyectos.

Comment: Y gracias a ti @lois6b por "localStorage", era algo que desconocía y nunca es tarde para aprender cosas nuevas.

Comment: Un placer @Pelayo :)

Answer (score 8):

Puedes guardarlo en la cache del navegador con javascript. En la parte donde se reciben los datos mediante:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
localStorage.setItem("usuario", <?= json_encode($_POST['usuario']) ?>);
</script>
```

Y cuando vuelvas al formulario mediante el DOM puedes poner el valor a la caja de texto con:

```
document.getElementById("usuario").value = localStorage.getItem("usuario");
```

Bibliografía de interés:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Muchas gracias por el consejo. Soy relativamente nuevo en esto de responder... Hasta ahora he sido un mero espectador...

Comment: Pues genial, ya no eres [un mero espectador](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nd2UaEXmhg8/WfynFWMOXWI/AAAAAAAAwTg/DEFyldizJUoVFzvck9LsSHv1wogZdWiDQCLcBGAs/s1600/Mero%2Bespectador.jpg) si no un respondedor del sitio :D Aunque recuerda ser más paciente la proxima vez, para dar tiempo al usuario a editar la pregunta con sus intentos y problemas. Si resuelves demasiado rapido, se acostumbran a no explicar o añadir nada a la pregunta y eso baja la calidad de las preguntas y del sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima. muchas gracias míster.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @Txapel todo ayuda es de buen agrado.

Comment: He mejorado tu respuesta cambiando la etiqueta errónea `<php?` por `<?=` (la que querías usar, imagino), corrigiendo el agujero de seguridad ([XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)) haciendo uso de [`json_encode()`](https://php.net/es/json_encode), cambiando la `L` que debe estar en minúscula y agregando un enlace a la documentación. Te doy mi +1 aunque haya maneras más sencillas de hacerlo :)